# Paypal subscription to different number of projects

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I am trying to create a subscription feature on my site. The users can subscribe to a number of projects (from 1 to 30). The price of a projet: 10$.

For subscribing I use a the Subscription button. I validate the payment using the IPN from paypal. All ok.

Now I want to give to users the possibility to change the number of projects they are subscribed for. But the paypal doesn't allow an increasing of payment more than 20%.

How can I change the user's subscription ? Should I remove his profile (not sure if I understant what it is) and create a new one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you saw in the documentation, PayPal Subscriptions product doesn't seem like a good match for your requirements. You could have someone re-subscribe with new (higher) premium, but you probably would be better off with a product that allowed you to simply change the recurring amount billed.

PayPal has several other products that allow you to do that; hopefully one will meet your needs. In particular look at Recurring Payments & Reference Transactions (within PayPal's classic product suite) or Future Payments (within PayPal's RESTful API suite).